# AsyncTask: onPostExecute is not being invoked

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I am trying to get the onPostExecute() method invoked after finishing the doInBackground() method and then passed the custom `arrayList<ItemDTO>` to the Map activity but onPostExecute method is not being invoked. I am not getting any Output in the Logcat as asign that it was invoked. How can I fix it?

I have debugged it and I can see the data in the ArrayList data object.

I appreciate any help.

**GetLLRD class**

```
public class GetLLRD {
    Context mContext;

    public void post_selected(String json, Context context) {
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(json);
        context = this.mContext;
    }

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<ItemDTO>> {


        @Override
        protected List<ItemDTO> doInBackground(String... params) {

          .
          .
          .
          .

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Type listType = new TypeToken<List<ItemDTO>>() {
                }.getType();
                ArrayList<ItemDTO> data = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), listType);
          .
          .
          .
          .     


            return data;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ItemDTO> result) {

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
                    System.out.println("The method onPostExcute() in GETLLRD class was invoked  again");
                }
            }, 1*30 * 1000);

            if (result != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Map.class);
                intent.putExtra("list",result);
                mContext.startActivity(intent); 

            }else{
                Log.e("123", "Avoiding null pointer, the dat is null in the GETLLRD class!!!");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**MapDataJSON  class with the inner class ItemDTo which I need to get the data from the JSON string that I am getting from the Server.**

```
public class MapDataJSON {
    ArrayList<ItemDTO> items;

    public MapDataJSON(ArrayList<ItemDTO> items) {
        super();
        this.items = items;
    }

    public ArrayList<ItemDTO> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<ItemDTO> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public static class ItemDTO  implements Serializable  {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
        double latitude;
        double longitude;
        int route;
        String direction;

        public ItemDTO(double latitude, double longitude, int route,
                String direction) {
            super();
            this.latitude = latitude;
            this.longitude = longitude;
            this.route = route;
            this.direction = direction;
        }

        public double getLatitude() {
            return latitude;
        }

        public double getLongitude() {
            return longitude;
        }

        public int getRoute() {
            return route;
        }

        public String getDirection() {
            return direction;
        }

        public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
            this.latitude = latitude;
        }

        public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }

        public void setRoute(int route) {
            this.route = route;
        }

        public void setDirection(String direction) {
            this.direction = direction;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you call `MyAsyncTask` again from `onPostExecute`, from a `Handler'?

Comment: Because I want to update the data in my map activity every 30 seconds? I dont know whether it the right Approach is?

Comment: I can see few problems here, including memory leak. I would use an `alarmManager`. I also guess you would want to run it as a background service. Set the alarm inside a service and use `onPostExecute` to notify the alarm that the current task is done and start another cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not actually overriding the correct method signature of AsyncTask

it should be

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<ItemDTO> result)
```

by specifying ArrayList you're changing the method signature. This is why it's useful to use the Override annotation as your ide or compiler will tell you the method signature doesn't match.